# Switch handling with global arrays

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

Say I have 2 global arrays:

```
$Global:Values  = @(1..100)
$Global:Test = @(75, 50, 25, 101)
```

Then I create a `Switch` by piping `$Global:Test` into a `ForEach` loop by using different conditions which I tried troubleshooting to get any kind of response:

```
$Global:Test | ForEach-Object ($_) {
    $_
    Switch ($_) {
        ($_ -contains $Global:Values) {Write-Host "Excellent"}
        ($_ -in $Global:Values) {Write-Host "Satisfactory"}
        ($_ -eq "25") {Write-Host "Unsatisfactory"}
        Default {Write-Host "Invalid Grade"}
    }
}
```

Output:

```
75
Invalid Grade
50
Invalid Grade
25
Invalid Grade
101
Invalid Grade
```

All of these `switch` statements do not work except the `default`. I don't know what I'm missing, but I'm sure it's a simple mistake I'm overlooking. Can anyone help me spot this mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foreach()` statement is not the same as the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, and you seem to be combining the syntax of both.

Additionally, you're using the `switch` statement incorrectly.

The part you're trying to match against needs to be a value:

```
switch ($something)
{
    5 { "5 thing" }
    (10 + 10) { "20 thing" }
}
```

or a scriptblock expression that returns a truthy or falsey value:

```
switch ($something)
{
    { $_ -gt 5 } { "do > 5 thing" }
    { Test-SomeCondition -Value $_ } { "do other thing" }
}
```

So you want the scriptblock form, but you're using parentheses.

So here's the `ForEach-Object` form:

```
$Global:Test | ForEach-Object {
    Switch ($_) {
        {$_ -contains $Global:Values} {Write-Host "Excellent"}
        {$_ -in $Global:Values} {Write-Host "Satisfactory"}
        "25" {Write-Host "Unsatisfactory"}
        Default {Write-Host "Invalid Grade"}
    }
}
```

or the `foreach` form:

```
foreach($value in $Global:Test) {
    Switch ($value) {
        {$_ -contains $Global:Values} {Write-Host "Excellent"}
        {$_ -in $Global:Values} {Write-Host "Satisfactory"}
        "25" {Write-Host "Unsatisfactory"}
        Default {Write-Host "Invalid Grade"}
    }
}
```

Also of note, the `switch` statement can actually work directly with arrays, so you don't have to iterate first. Basic example:

```
switch (1..10)
{
    { $_ -gt 5 } { "Second Half"}
    default: { "First Half" }
}
```

So with yours, maybe:

```
Switch ($Global:Test) {
    {$_ -contains $Global:Values} {Write-Host "Excellent"}
    {$_ -in $Global:Values} {Write-Host "Satisfactory"}
    "25" {Write-Host "Unsatisfactory"}
    Default {Write-Host "Invalid Grade"}
}
```

Small addendum: stop using Global variables!

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware that I was using the wrong parentheses for the Switch. I know I shouldn't be using Global variables, but I have to because I'm practicing with other scripts. I appreciate you pointing it out! :)